# Connection to database using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

It is my first time using PHP. I am using XAMPP on a mac.

MySQL, Apache, and localhost:8080 are all working right now.
I created this file called test.php and saved it inside lampp/htdocs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Connection</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  $servername = "localhost:8080";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn)
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Connected successfully";
  }
?>



</body>
</html>
```

However, when I go to localhose:8080/test.php a blank page opens but nothing shows up

Comment: Use this to turn on error display. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); And check your web server erro log.

Comment: I tried that. It's because I cannot put an argument inside 'mysqli_connect_error()' However, now it shows me <br>Connection failed: Connection refused<br> Do you know why this happens

Comment: `localhost:8080` is your webserver, MySQL port usually is 3306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 8080 is for your web server. Your MySQL server listens by default on port 3306. You can check in your XAMPP settings if the port is different, but it should be 3306. This means that you can omit the port number.

To connect to the database using mysqli you only need 3 lines of code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name', 3306); // you can omit the last argument
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

Answer (score 0):

The servername argument to `mysqli_connect` been to be **just** the servername.

If you want to supply a port number then that goes in the **fifth** argument to `mysqli_connect`. It isn't mixed into the first.

That said:

1. since `localhose:8080/test.php` shows a web page, it is clear that you are running your HTTP server on port 8080, not your database server.
2. for performance reasons you should prefer using a socket connection to MySQL/MariaDB, not a TCP/IP port

Comment: It looks like localhost will auto do that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: @JasonK — Yes, but ports are the domain of TCP/IP and not local sockets.

Comment: I just tested it with the code from the manual. Using port with locaclhost. It's still claiming Localhost via UNIX socket.

Comment: @JasonK That's new to me. What system are you trying this on?

Comment: ub 20.04 LTS php 7.4.3

Comment: @JasonK I can't reproduce it. I even checked the source code. The socket is used only if the hostname argument is `localhost`. If you include port number then TCP/IP connection is used.